# Does the `Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool` call `rollback` when returning a Connection to the pool?

Tags: transactions, jdbc, connection-pooling

I’ve [heard it said](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31754214/642706) that a good JDBC connection pool should call [`rollback`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback--) when it returns a connection back to the pool. The purpose is to resolve any possibly still pending transaction.

Does the [`Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) in [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) 8 do this, or do something else to clean-up any pending transaction left open?

I tried reading [the Tomcat 8.0.24 source code](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi)<sup>†</sup>. The use of interceptor, proxy, wrapping, and subclassing made for more spaghetti than I could follow. I could not determine the behavior when calling a pooled connection’s [`close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close--) method, as with common JDBC code using [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) code ([`AutoClosable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)).

---

<sup>†</sup> `apache-tomcat-8.0.24-src > modules > jdbc-pool > src > main > java > org > apache > tomcat > jdbc > pool` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Why read the source when you can read [the documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Tomcat_JDBC_Enhanced_Attributes)?

> rollbackOnReturn
>
> (boolean) If autoCommit==false then the pool can terminate the transaction by calling rollback on the connection as it is returned to the pool Default value is false.

Comment: So, how would you read that? "No, by default Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool does *not* rollback any possibly lingering transaction"?

Comment: yes, with autoCommit==false pool would contain open transaction.